# Crear tabla html bidimensional con js desde lista python

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría crear una tabla bidimensional, en la cual el eje x sean las fechas (con formato título ) y el eje y los nombres de los datos (también con formato título ).

Recojo los datos desde un JSON:

```
{"dataval": [ 
    {
       "date":"2014-01-01 00:00:00",
       "value":25776510,
       "name":"Nom1"
    },
    {
        "date":"2014-02-01 00:00:00",
        "value":789,
       "name":"Nom1"
    },
    {
        "date":"2014-01-01 00:00:00",
        "value":0,
        "name":"Nom2"
    },
    {
        "date":"2014-02-01 00:00:00",
        "value":0,
        "name":"Nom2"
     }
]}
```

Trato de recorrer los datos y unirlos en un string pero no lo consigo.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.dataval.length; i++) {
    date_now = data.dataval[i]['date'];
    name_now = data.dataval[i]['name'];

    if (i == 0){

        date = date_now;
        date_bef = date_now;
        table += "<th>" + date + "</th>";

        name = name_now;
        name_bef = name_now;
        table += "<th>" + name + "</th>";

    }else{

        date_bef = data.dataval[i-1]['date'];
        name_bef = data.dataval[i-1]['name'];

    }      

    if (date_bef != date_now){

        date = date_now;
        table += "<th>" + date + "</th>";
    }    

    if (name_bef != name_now){

        name = name_now;
        names_col += "<th>" + name + "</th>";
    }

    name = data.dataval[i]['name'];
    value = data.dataval[i]['value'];
    table += '<tr>' + value + '</tr>';


}
table +="</tr>";
table += "</table>";
$("#tbody_tabla").html(table);
```

Me gustaría añadir también que el resultado final en HTML sería:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>2014-01-01 00:00:00</th>        
    <th>2014-02-01 00:00:00</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Nom1</th>
    <td>25776510</td>       
    <td>789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2014-02-01 00:00:00</th>
    <td>0</td>      
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Didina, faltaría que des mayor detalle, ¿ese objeto que has mostrado es un diccionario en Python o en JavaScript?, ¿estás usando algún web framework?, ¿como estás pasando los datos de Python a JavaScript?

Comment: Esa es la idea de la pregunta, que muestres el código que falla. Si mostraras código que funciona y resuelve el problema en la pregunta, entonces creo que no tendrías necesidad de publicar la pregunta, ¿no lo crees? Además, aquí habrán personas que te ayudarán a corregir ese código :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Si, tienes toda la razón, me daba un poco de vergüenza mostrar el código desastre...

Comment: @César Voy a editar la pregunta para explicar más como es el objeto

Comment: @DidinaDeen en la ultima tabla que pones de ejemplo creo que deberías cambiar el formato y poner un ejemplo del resultado esperado con los valores reales. Así como está ahora es un poco difícil entender como se debe mostrar la tabla.

Comment: Ok, lo cambio para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres puede lograrse fácilmente con un [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para hacer una agrupación doble de tus datos primero por filas y luego por columnas.

Este método sirve para transformar cualquier *collección* en un *valor* u otra *collección*, en tu caso estoy transformando el arreglo en un objeto donde sus propiedades son las filas y cada una de estas contiene otro objeto donde sus propiedades son las fechas y finalmente estas tienen el valor de la celda.

```js
$(function() {
  // cachear una referencia a la tabla para aumentar la eficiencia en los selectores
  var $tabla = $('#resultado').append('<thead><tr></tr></thead>');
  // insertar un header
  var $header = $tabla.find('tr');
  // agregar cabecera vacia
  $header.append('<th></th>');
  // agregar el body de la tabla
  $tabla.append('<tbody></tbody>');
  var $tbody = $tabla.find('tbody');

  // tus datos
  var data = {
    "dataval": [{
      "date": "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
      "value": 25776510,
      "name": "Nom1"
    }, {
      "date": "2014-02-01 00:00:00",
      "value": 789,
      "name": "Nom1"
    }, {
      "date": "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
      "value": 0,
      "name": "Nom2"
    }, {
      "date": "2014-02-01 00:00:00",
      "value": 0,
      "name": "Nom2"
    }]
  };

  // primero tienes que agupar todos los datos
  // se agrupa primero por nombre y luego por fecha
  var datosTabla = data.dataval.reduce(function(curr, item) {
    // si nos encontramos un item que no ha sido guardado creamos un objeto vacío
    if (!curr[item.name]) {
      curr[item.name] = {};
    }
    // creamos una propiedad con el valor de "date" para usarla al imprimir las cabeceras y le asignamos el valor correspondiente
    curr[item.name][item.date] = item.value;
    return curr;
  }, {});

  // esta variable sirve para imprimir los headers y hacer más eficiente el programa
  // básicamente los headers se imprimen en la primera iteración así que no imprimimos más si ya fueron creados
  var headers = false;

  $.each(datosTabla, function(key, item) {
    // creamos una nueva fila en el cuerpo de la tabla y la seleccionamos
    var $row = $tbody.append('<tr></tr>').last();
    // le agregamos una columna con el valor de "name"
    $row.append('<td>' + key + '</td>');
    // iteramos por todas los "dates" o columnas
    $.each(item, function(keyRow, itemRow) {
      // si no se han creados los headers los creamos en esta iteración
      if (!headers) {
        $header.append('<td>' + keyRow + '</td>');
      }
      // agregamos cada elemento de la columna
      $row.append('<td>' + itemRow + '</td>')
    });

    // indicamos que ya no es necesario volver a imprimir los headers
    headers = true;
  });

});
```

```css
table#resultado {
  width: 100%;
  border: gray solid 1px;
}
table#resultado td {
  border: gray solid 1px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.8.2/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultado">
</table>
```